Losing Data when using PDFQuery to convert PDF to XML
I am trying to convert a PDF file to an XML file using PDFQuery and then extracting data from it using bbox coordinates. However, the converted XML file is often missing some of the data present in the PDF.
import pdfquery


def loader(x):

 pdf=pdfquery.PDFQuery("holdlines1.pdf")
 pdf.load(x)
 l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7=([] for x in range(7))

 # sheet="1888.8, 42.229, 1911.238, 58.129"
 # line="1544.88, 49.873, 1586.476, 62.548 // 1537.2, 49.873, 1592.954, 62.548"
 # plant="1654.32, 42.229, 1676.758, 58.129"
 # indexn="1710.48, 42.151, 1719.247, 59.551"
 # drawing="1770.24, 42.229, 1836.362, 58.129"
 # revno="1941.84, 40.209, 1963.871, 59.979"

 for i in pdf.pq("LTPage"):
    
     for j in pdf.pq("LTTextLineHorizontal"):
        
         
         print((pdf.pq(j).text()))
         if "HOLD" in (pdf.pq(j).text()):
            l1.append(pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("1888.8, 42.229, 1911.238, 58.129")').text())
            l2.append(pdf.pq(j).text())
            l3.append(pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("1544.88, 49.873, 1586.476, 62.548")').text())
            l4.append(pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("1654.32, 42.229, 1676.758, 58.129")').text())
            l5.append(pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("1710.48, 42.151, 1719.247, 59.551")').text())
            l6.append(pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("1770.24, 42.229, 1836.362, 58.129")').text())
            l7.append(pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("1941.84, 40.209, 1963.871, 59.979")').text())


 return l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7

This is the function I am using. The x argument takes in the page number.
The data I want is "HOLD - VD - MEP","HOLD - STR - CV", and other variations but basically it always contains "HOLD".
The code works fine for the data present in the xml file, but the xml file itself misses some of the present in the PDF.
Here is the code I am using to convert the PDF to XML and write it into a file to check:
import pdfquery

pdf=pdfquery.PDFQuery("holdlines1.pdf")
pdf.load()

pdf.tree.write("holdlines1.xml",pretty_print=True)

Screenshot of a part of the PDF I am working with for reference:

I do not understand why is it missing only some of the data, and converting most of the data just fine.There are a lot of questions about conversion from PDF to XML but I cannot find any where the data from the PDF is missed in the XML.
